# Custom shortcut for symbol?

Tags: shortcut-keys

How do I make a custom shortcut that types an @ sign? I've tried `Meta+2`, `Hyper+2`, `Super+2`, `AtlGr+2`, `RAlt+2`, `AltR+2`, `Right-Alt+2` and a couple more but can't get it to work.

Edit: Oh, I should mention that I have a Swedish keyboard, so @ is AtlGr+2 for me, no clue how to write that though. Stupid of me to forget to mention that.

Comment: can you get a keycode of a custom key you want to use with `xev`, and set it with `xmodmap -e 'keycode YOUR_KEYCODE_HERE = 64'` ?

Comment: What? Even if I understood that, which I don't, it doesn't look right

Comment: Do you want to map a key to @?

Comment: No, I want to map a button to write my email, which includes an @

Comment: So, you require a button to produce '@', for usage in an email, but your keyboard doesn't currently have an appropriate button?

Comment: My keyboard has an @, but the custom shortcut functionality on Kubuntu (found at System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts) requires me to type out the @ as a key combination of `{Something}+2` and I can't figure out what that `{Something}` should be

Comment: For example, would I want to write an exclamation mark it would be `Shift+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to try to tweak the modifier key to choose the right level. These settings don't come pre-package but can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

If you go to *Show Applications>Tweaks>Keyboard & Mouse>Additional Layout Options>Key to choose the 3rd level* you can set the key you want as a modifier for the 3rd level of 2 (@).